Grid System - unable to align 3 columns in a row
I have read the docs and have googled - unable to find an answer.  I have a parallax bootstrap slide.  In the first slide I am trying to make 3 div columns equal height and width side by side in a single row.  Code is below.. however when rendered, each column is stacked on top of each other, so there is basically 1 column.  Assistance please?
  <div style="--swiper-navigation-color: #fff; --swiper-pagination-color: #fff" class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="parallax-bg" style="
          background-image: url(https:// domain .com/assets/img/moonscape.jpg);
        " data-swiper-parallax="-23%"></div>
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="title" data-swiper-parallax="-300">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="subtitle" data-swiper-parallax="-200">Subtitle</div>
        <div class="text" data-swiper-parallax="-100">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam
                  dictum mattis velit, sit amet faucibus felis iaculis nec. Nulla
                  laoreet justo vitae porttitor porttitor. Suspendisse in sem justo.
                  Integer laoreet magna nec elit suscipit, ac laoreet nibh euismod.
                  Aliquam hendrerit lorem at elit facilisis rutrum. Ut at
                  ullamcorper velit. Nulla ligula nisi, imperdiet ut lacinia nec,
                  tincidunt ut libero. Aenean feugiat non eros quis feugiat.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam
                  dictum mattis velit, sit amet faucibus felis iaculis nec. Nulla
                  laoreet justo vitae porttitor porttitor. Suspendisse in sem justo.
                  Integer laoreet magna nec elit suscipit, ac laoreet nibh euismod.
                  Aliquam hendrerit lorem at elit facilisis rutrum. Ut at
                  ullamcorper velit. Nulla ligula nisi, imperdiet ut lacinia nec,
                  tincidunt ut libero. Aenean feugiat non eros quis feugiat.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam
                  dictum mattis velit, sit amet faucibus felis iaculis nec. Nulla
                  laoreet justo vitae porttitor porttitor. Suspendisse in sem justo.
                  Integer laoreet magna nec elit suscipit, ac laoreet nibh euismod.
                  Aliquam hendrerit lorem at elit facilisis rutrum. Ut at
                  ullamcorper velit. Nulla ligula nisi, imperdiet ut lacinia nec,
                  tincidunt ut libero. Aenean feugiat non eros quis feugiat.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>                    
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="title" data-swiper-parallax="-300">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="subtitle" data-swiper-parallax="-200">Subtitle</div>
        <div class="text" data-swiper-parallax="-100">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam
            dictum mattis velit, sit amet faucibus felis iaculis nec. Nulla
            laoreet justo vitae porttitor porttitor. Suspendisse in sem justo.
            Integer laoreet magna nec elit suscipit, ac laoreet nibh euismod.
            Aliquam hendrerit lorem at elit facilisis rutrum. Ut at
            ullamcorper velit. Nulla ligula nisi, imperdiet ut lacinia nec,
            tincidunt ut libero. Aenean feugiat non eros quis feugiat.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="title" data-swiper-parallax="-300">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="subtitle" data-swiper-parallax="-200">Subtitle</div>
        <div class="text" data-swiper-parallax="-100">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam
            dictum mattis velit, sit amet faucibus felis iaculis nec. Nulla
            laoreet justo vitae porttitor porttitor. Suspendisse in sem justo.
            Integer laoreet magna nec elit suscipit, ac laoreet nibh euismod.
            Aliquam hendrerit lorem at elit facilisis rutrum. Ut at
            ullamcorper velit. Nulla ligula nisi, imperdiet ut lacinia nec,
            tincidunt ut libero. Aenean feugiat non eros quis feugiat.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="title" data-swiper-parallax="-300">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="subtitle" data-swiper-parallax="-200">Subtitle</div>
        <div class="text" data-swiper-parallax="-100">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam
            dictum mattis velit, sit amet faucibus felis iaculis nec. Nulla
            laoreet justo vitae porttitor porttitor. Suspendisse in sem justo.
            Integer laoreet magna nec elit suscipit, ac laoreet nibh euismod.
            Aliquam hendrerit lorem at elit facilisis rutrum. Ut at
            ullamcorper velit. Nulla ligula nisi, imperdiet ut lacinia nec,
            tincidunt ut libero. Aenean feugiat non eros quis feugiat.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>


Are you sure you are correctly importing/using Bootstrap 5? I tested your HTML using Bootstrap 5 and the row correctly renders with three columns. When testing your HTML using Bootstrap 3, I get the results you describe (all columns stacked on top of one another).
Here is a codepen I made that shows your HTML working when correctly importing Bootstrap 5
If you are using a CDN, try swapping it to this:
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

Alternatively, you can just add display: flex on the row class.
If you need more information on getting started with Bootstrap 5, visit this link.

you, sir, are correct. thank you so much

you must check correctly your CSS or bootstrap like this:
CSS <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
BootStrap <linkhref="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
